# automatic run php code without user control

Tags: php, bank

I don't know how to call this.

if I wrote a php script to calculate an interest for saving account.

how can I tell the program to run the script on the end of the day without user monitoring. such as 0.00am or the server start.

Comment: You need a cron job (if your server supports it).

Comment: Which OS? And do you have access to the hosting machine, or is this hosted on server somewhere?

Comment: on localhost os windows7 webserver apache

Answer (score 2):

If you are on UNIX server, [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is the way to go. On Windows machine use Scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Call the [PHP file via CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) using [Crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), if you're on Windows try [pyCron](http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm).

Answer (score 0):

you need to run cron jobs look wiki [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for more information. hope this helps.